# Selection disappears in EKCalendarChooser

Tags: ios

I show EKCalendarChooser in popover. When user selects a calendar in the chooser I get its calendarIdentifier. Everything goes smooth till this point but When you reopen the popover the selection in the chooser disappears. How to maintain the selection or how to reselect the calendar again when user open the chooser popover again.

If EKCalendarChooser is normal UITableView I can easily match my db value with that of the displayed cell and make it selected. But here how do I set EKCalendarChooser tablecell selected? I do have the calendarIdentifier...any Ideas?

plz help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try looking at the EKCalendarChooser documentation? Everything you're asking is right there. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EKCalendarChooserClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKCalendarChooser/selectedCalendars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the user works with the EKCalendarChooser, use the `calendarChooserSelectionDidChange:` delegate method to keep track as the user changes the selection. You can store the `selectedCalendars` property value each time this method is called.

Then, the next time the EKCalendarChooser appears, set its `selectedCalendars` property to the selection you previously saved.

Comment: Thanks for the Input matt. I kept thinking that selectedCalendars was  readonly. Well my bad. You saved my day. Thanks again. I implemented and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to build a data layer to your application with reference to MVC design pattern see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html).

Save the popover selection state (and the other data) at the data layer (model).

After that, access this data layer (model) each time u open the popover and configure the popover according the data.

Anyway, to to make cells selected or deselected in UITableViewDelegate methods:

```
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:
```

Comment: I do not want to recreate EKCalendarChooser for a simple matter of keepin it always selected. I understand how we can keep up a selection each time if a normal UITableView is reopened in a popover and done so at many times but this is different. Thanks for the answer. I Welcome more practical answers.

Comment: U shouldn't recreate anything! never! Just manage your data apart from your view stuff, that's all. Cheers!